# transferspreadsheet range error:3011 stuck at column "IV"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using the below function to export columns to access DB. It works perfectly well for all the columns before "IV" but gives an error for all the ranges in and after column "IV". My sheet name is "Perm-1" and range is IV3:IV4 in below example. Could not find anything on the google or Microsoft documentation. Anyone faced similar error please let me know if you were able to resolve it.

```
Public Sub Excel_Access_Export(accDB As Access.Application, tblName As String)

accDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        TableName:=tblName, _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Perm-1$IV3:IV4"
End Sub
```

Edit:: Error Message: "MS Access cannot find the object 'Perm-1$IV3:IV4'. Make sure the object exists and spell its name correctly. If this is not a local object, check your network connection or contact server administration"

Comment: Please post full error message and not just the number 3011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column IV is column 256. Access 2007-2010 has a limit of 255 columns. Transferspreadsheet shares these column limits, but (perhaps more to the point, as it turns out) is also restricted by an outdated excel object model (256 columns and 65536 rows).

Here is some sample code that works around the columns issue. (You can work around the row limit in the same way - copy it to rows 1 to 65536 and import in chunks of up to 65535 rows.) I added a new sheet, "Staging" that is simply an empty sheet to temporarily hold the stuff you want to transfer. For this example I'm transferring just one column.

There may be better workarounds out there but for current purposes this is a POC. And yeah, I'm using "thisworkbook" and the transfer is using "activeworkbook".

```
Sub test()
    Dim accDB As Access.Application

    Set accDB = New Access.Application
    accDB.Application.Visible = True
    accDB.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Bench\Database11.accdb", True
    Call Excel_Access_Export(accDB, "Table1", 257)
End Sub

Public Sub Excel_Access_Export(accDB As Access.Application, tblName As String, col As Long)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Staging").Columns(1)
        .ClearContents
        .Value = thisWorkbook.Sheets("Perm-1").Columns(col).Value
    End With
    accDB.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        TableName:=tblName, Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, Range:="Staging$A3:A4"
End Sub
```

Comment: But I am creating a seperate table for each column here. For eg: Column A is table1, Column B is table 2 and so on.

Comment: Even though you're only transferring one column and 2 rows (one being the header), as soon as you ask TransferSpreadsheet to look for data at column 256, it will break. The workaround is to break your data across multiple spreadsheets. I'll update my answer to show you one workaround for columns. FWIW It also breaks on 65537 rows. I suspect TransferSpreadsheet has not been updated since the days when Excel was limited to 256 columns and 65536 rows.

Comment: You are mistaken over the direction of transfer. OP is transferring data from Excel to Access, not from Access to Excel. He has well over 256 columns of data in Excel that he is transferring to multiple tables in Access. Go read his code. Also, when something breaks at 255/256 and at 65535/65536, it's generally not a coincidence.